# DeltaManipulation.Rotation how determine if rotation is clockwise or counterclockwise?

Tags: c#, wpf, touch

I need determine rotation direction using DeltaManipulation.Rotation.
The code work, but return false information everytime when complete rotation happen clockwise or counterclockwise.
What im doing wrong?

```
 int oldValue = 0;
 int realValue;
 private void ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;

        MyRotateTransform.Angle += e.DeltaManipulation.Rotation;
        int angle = (int)MyRotateTransform.Angle;
        realValue = angle % 360;

        if (realValue < 0)
        {
            realValue = 360 - (-realValue);
        }


        if (realValue > oldValue)
        {
            //clockwise rotation
            oldValue = realValue;
        }

        if (realValue < oldValue)
        {

              //counterclockwise rotation
            oldValue = realValue;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not check the accumulated (and normalized) rotation angle in `MyRotateTransform.Angle`. Instead, just check `e.DeltaManipulation.Rotation`.

If it's less than zero, the rotation was counterclockwise, it it's greater than zero the rotation was clockwise:

```
if (e.DeltaManipulation.Rotation < 0)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("counterclockwise");
}
else if (e.DeltaManipulation.Rotation > 0)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("clockwise");
}
```